# JDBC Template as client of Apache Phoenix

Tags: hbase, jdbctemplate, apache-phoenix

Is it possible to use the JDBC Template to interact with the Phoenix over HBase. If yes, what will be the pros and cons of that. If not, why and what should be the alternative for that?

Comment: Anyone any answer, please.

Comment: If you solved this, I'll be happy to hear. I am able to query Phoenix using JDBCTemplate but for some reason I can't delete.

Comment: Both select and upsert queries worked fine with JDBCTemplate. You can see HBaseUpsertDataLayer at https://github.com/Flipkart/aesop/commit/40c2d837a759bac82cf213b6e1a079eea8774a6f.

Comment: Have you tried deleting entries using JDBCTemplate?

Comment: My use case of delete was making all the columns except the primary one, null (actually, an update). I didn't perform an actual delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoenix works with JDBCTemplate and Spring, using the JDBC driver org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver. Here is an example spring implementation  http://blog.csdn.net/eric_sunah/article/details/44494321 with connection pooling (the blog post is in Chinese but it translates well on chrome).

It's important to mention upsert, delete and update only seemed to work when executing as a block query.

I'm not certain of the pros and cons at this point, but I hope you find this helpful.